# Is this a CUDA thread synchronization issue or something else?

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, matrix-multiplication

I am very new to parallel programming and stack overflow. I am working on a matrix multiplication implementation using CUDA. I am using column order float arrays as matrix representations.

The algorithm I developed is a bit unique and goes as follows. Given a matrix an n x m matrix A and an m x k matrix B, I launch an n x k blocks with m threads in each block. Essentially, I launch a block for every entry in the resulting matrix, with each thread computing one multiplication for that entry. For example,

```
1 0 0     0 1 2  
0 1 0  *  3 4 5  
0 0 1     6 7 8
```

For the first entry in the resulting matrix I would launch each thread with

thread 0 computing 1 * 3
thread 1 computing 0 * 0
thread 2 computing 0 * 1

With each thread adding to a 0-initialized matrix. 
Right now, I am not getting a correct answer. I am getting this over and over again

```
0 0 2
0 0 5
0 0 8
```

My kernel function is below. Could this be a thread synchronization problem or am I screwing up array indexing or something?

```
    /*@param d_A: Column order matrix 
     *@param d_B: Column order matrix
     *@param d_result: 0-initialized matrix that kernels write to
     *@param dim_A: dimensionality of A (number of rows)
     *@param dim_B: dimensionality of B (number of rows)
     */
    __global__ void dot(float *d_A, float *d_B, float *d_result, int dim_A, int dim_B) {
        int n = blockIdx.x;
        int k = blockIdx.y;
        int m = threadIdx.x;

       float a = d_A[(m * dim_A) + n];
       float b = d_B[(k * dim_B) + m];
       //d_result[(k * dim_A) + n] += (a * b);

       syncthreads();
       float temp = d_result[(k*dim_A) + n];
       syncthreads();
       temp = temp + (a * b);
       syncthreads();
       d_result[(k*dim_A) + n] = temp;
       syncthreads();
    }
```

Comment: In `d_result[(k*dim_A) + n] = temp;` each thread in the block is writing to the same location overwriting each others result.

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea of using `syncthreads()` is wrong in this case. This API call has a **block** scope.

```
   1. syncthreads();
   2. float temp = d_result[(k*dim_A) + n];
   3. syncthreads();
   4. temp = temp + (a * b);
   5. syncthreads();
   6. d_result[(k*dim_A) + n] = temp;
   7. syncthreads();
```

The local variable `float temp;` has thread scope and using this synchronization barrier is senseless.
The pointer `d_result` is global memory pointer and using this synchronization barrier is also senseless. Note that there isn't available yet (maybe there will never be available) a barrier which synchronizes threads globally.

Typically the usage of `syncthreads()` is required when shared memory is used for computation. In this case you may want to use shared memory. *[Here](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/using-shared-memory-cuda-cc)* you could see an example of how to use shared memory and `syncthreads()` properly. *[Here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#shared-memory)* you have an example of matrix multiplication with shared memory.